# LibSVM format for sentiment analysis

Tags: c#, c++, svm, libsvm, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to find out what I'm doing wrong using the libSVM (C++ version).

Let's take 2 rows for example of my raw text file:

```
positive    Wonderful film that mixes documentary and fiction in a way that makes the spectator question: what is the extent of truth in documentary films or is there such a thing as an objective documentary.

negative    An unfunny, unworthy picture which is an undeserving end to Peter Sellers' career. It is a pity this movie was ever made.
```

From this I will transform it into what I suppose should be the correct libSVM format:
    label  feature:value feature:value ...

My labels are 0 (positive) and 1 (negative)

```
0 169:1 192:1 265:1 453:1 510:1 632:1 889:1 1411:3 2092:1 3118:1 3393:1 19363:1 19976:1 26895:1

1 51:1 241:1 864:1 1273:1 1768:1 14912:1 18807:1 25011:1 30846:1
```

From the raw text to the processed one, I remove the common stop words (a, the, ...).

Then from what I understood, a word is a feature.

If this sentence was the first:

```
Great movie
```

I would convert it to:

```
0 1:1 2:1
```

100th sentence:

```
Great actor

0 1:1 234:1
```

(I give the index 234 for actor as an example).

The value from what I understood is the number of occurrence of a word in the sentence.

So if I have:

```
great great great
```

I will get:

```
0 1:3
```

That's for how I convert.

When I use this file in LibSVM using Linear, with C from 1 to 10 (I tried 10 values because I thought it would change).

And actually I ALWAYS get the exact same confusion matrix and 51% accuracy.

Do I need to add more steps ? change the way I convert it ?

Because at the end I have a LOT of features (words) (more than 35k in my training file).

Is there anything I'm missing ?

I also tested with LibSVM implemented in C# and I get the same result.

For the dataset it's imdb (http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/)